# Условия в роутинге Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, редирект, роутинг

Как на laravel сделать условие в роутинге.
К примеру есть правило

```
Route::get('/','ReviewController@make');
```

нужно сделать редирект, что бы при определенном выставленном языке путь менялся автоматически на /ru
в общем как то так

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    if(\App::isLocale('ru')){
        return redirect('/ru');
    } else {
       //а вот тут надо сделать вызов этого метода из контроллера ReviewController@make - как это правильно сделать?
    }
});
```

Спасибо.

Comment: Правильно делать проверку в контроллере и там уже редиректить куда необходимо. Роутинг предназначен для связи пути с контроллером.

Answer (score 0):

А если так:

```
Route::get('/', function($router){
    if(\App::isLocale('ru')){
        return redirect('/ru');
    } else {
       $router->get('/', 'ReviewController@make');
    }    
});
```

?

Comment: Это вопрос или всё таки ответ?

Comment: Это предложение попробовать так